# Laravel how to get the email address using a listener

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to get the email address of the sender via an event listener. I am able to log them fine using the code below but I can't access it directly because it is set to private by Symfony. hence I get this error: `"Cannot access private property Symfony\Component\Mime\Address::$address"`

So my question is how can I get the sender's email since I need to filter them first?

Code:

```
public function handle(MessageSent $event){
      $message = $event->message;
      Log::info($message->getTo());//this logs the email
   }
```

Log Result:

```
array (
  0 => 
  Symfony\Component\Mime\Address::__set_state(array(
     'address' => 'email@email.com',
     'name' => 'Name',
  )),
)
```

But if I try this code below to check the email individually:

```
public function handle(MessageSent $event){
      $message = $event->message;
      
      foreach( $message->getTo() as $email ){
      info($email->address);//returns an error
      }
   }
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot access private property Symfony\Component\Mime\Address::$address
```

And if I use this code below to see what's happening

```
public function handle(MessageSent $event){
      $message = $event->message;      
      foreach( $message->getTo() as $email ){
         print_r($email);
      }
   }
```

Then I get this result:

```
Symfony\Component\Mime\Address Object ( [address:Symfony\Component\Mime\Address:private] => email@email.com [name:Symfony\Component\Mime\Address:private] => )
```

Comment: Did you try using `$email->getAddress()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that there is a getter method for most of the Mime values, as in your case for the [address](https://github.com/symfony/mime/blob/6.1/Address.php#L58).

```php
$email->getAddress();
```

Comment: thank you. that solved it! I wonder what keywords I should've used to get that answer.

Comment: The easiest way would have been to google for Symfony\Component\Mime\Address getters or something similar to that, it would also show you similar answers or the github page that I linked. Glad it worked out for you!

Comment: If you don't mind marking my post as the correct answer, that'd be great:)